# Version of rpm before update?

Tags: rpm

Some days ago a rpm package was updated. In my case openssh.

Today I wanted to now: "What was the version before the update?"

Up to now I found not way to answer this question.

Does RPM, in my case OpenSuSE, have a history of the changes, so that I can get this information?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such command to get the history. You may check the [history file](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Libzypp_history) located at `/var/log/zypp/history` for the relevant info, if you have used zypper to install/update/remove the package.

[zypper equivalent of “rug history” command](https://www.suse.com/communities/blog/zypper-equivalent-of-rug-history-command/)

> Any packages installed or updated through zypper are logged in
>   `/var/log/zypp/history`. The bad news is that the file also logs some
>   other output so you can’t just `cat /var/log/zypp/history` to get the
>   equivalent output to ‘rug history’.
>
> What you can do however is process `/var/log/zypp/history` to produce
>   a similar output by using the ‘cut’ command:
>
> ```
> cut -d "|" -f 1-4 -s --output-delimiter " | " /var/log/zypp/history | grep -v " radd "
> ```